# Pandas dataframe. Add an aditional row header merging all columns

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I want to add a "second" header to my excel using pandas dataframe.
The excel has his values and header. But I want to add a new row above the header with just one column (the size of all columns header). And text centered.
Something like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html), but text is not centered:

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Result'], df.columns])
```

EDIT:

```
import string

# Creating a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 6), columns=list('ABCDEF'))


# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("test.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

# Create custom style
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=1, index=False)

# Get workbook and worksheet objects
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

merge_format = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center'})

len_cols = len(df.columns)
#set merge_range by length of colums names
len_cols = len(df.columns)
worksheet.merge_range(0, 0, 0, len_cols - 1, 'Result', merge_format)

writer.save()
```

Comment: I have this error: NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It works!! But I have a question: How "d = dict(enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 1))" and "worksheet.merge_range(f'A1:{d[len_cols]}1', 'Result', merge_format)" works? I don't undestand those lines. Also, why we put startrow=1 in to_excel method? Again, thank you.

Comment: @Keras-JOB - It is a bit trick. Excel need defined last column name. Here `F1` by length of columns. So is used dictionary `d` for mapping. So `6:'F'` in dict generate `F` by looking for `6`.

Comment: @Keras-JOB - So possible dynamic generate columns names (if not larger like 26, what is Z)

Comment: Note `merge_range()` supports `(row, col)` notation so it would be easier to use that here like `worksheet.merge_range(0, 0, 0, len_cols - 1)`. See : https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-merge-range

Comment: @Keras-JOB - Answer was edited and simplier now.